# how to group by getting the highest amount while keeping the row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

How would you get the rows in the same `Bar` with the highest `Amount`. I have this sample data.

```
Foo | Bar | Amount
1   | A   | 0
43  | A   | 120
1   | B   | 0
43  | B   | 120
1   | C   | 0
43  | C   | 105
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
Foo | Bar | Amount
1   | A   | 0
43  | A   | 120
```

**OR**

```
Foo | Bar | Amount
1   | B   | 0
43  | B   | 120
```

Any of the two above will do just fine since I only need the highest `Amount`. I have this query but doesn't seem correct.

```
select
    Foo
    ,max(Bar) as Bar
    ,max(Amount) as Amount
from Table1
group by Foo
```

I am getting

```
Foo | Bar | Amount
1   | C   | 0
43  | C   | 120
```

The result should kept the values in a row.

Any help would much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are applying MAx to a string so it will get the last one. You should use MIN if you want to get A.

Edit:

Based on your comment, the following will work;

```
WITH CTE as(
Select t1.Bar from #TBL1 t1
where t1.Amount = (Select MAX(Amount) From #TBL1)
group by t1.Bar)
Select t1.* From CTE ct
join #TBL1 t1
on t1.Bar = ct.Bar
```

Just replace #TBL with your table name.

Comment: Yes. using `min()` would solve the problem but what if the result you are looking for is in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
SELECT TOP 1
 Foo ,
 Bar,
 Amount
FROM Table1
order by 
Amount desc
,Bar asc
```

Comment: Thanks but the results should get the rows in the same `Bar` with the highest amount while retaining the row values

Answer (score 0):

If any one of the 'Bar' rows which have maximum 'Amount' is fine,
hope the below query helps..

```
select * from table1 where bar in (
  select bar
  from(
    select bar,max(amount) maxim
    from table1 
    group by bar
    order by maxim desc
  ) where rownum =1
);
```

Edit :

```
 select * from table1 where bar in (
      select bar
      from(
Select top(1) bar,maxim from (
        select bar,max(amount) maxim
        from table1 
        group by bar
        order by maxim desc
      )) 
    );
```

Comment: I am getting error in `rownumber = 1`. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh..this query is tested in oracle..need to get an alternative of rownum in Sql server.

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the maximum `Amount` per `Bar`:

```
SELECT
  Foo,
  Bar,
  Amount,
  MaxAmount = MAX(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Bar)
FROM
  dbo.Table1
;
```

For your example the above query would return this result set:

```
Foo  Bar  Amount  MaxAmount
---  ---  ------  ---------
1    A    0       120
43   A    120     120
1    B    0       120
43   B    120     120
1    C    0       105
43   C    105     105
```

Now use `ORDER BY MaxAmount DESC, Bar ASC` (or `... Bar DESC`) and apply `TOP (1) WITH TIES` to the result to return a subset representing just one `Bar`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  Foo,
  Bar,
  Amount,
  MaxAmount = MAX(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Bar)
FROM
  dbo.Table1
ORDER BY
  MaxAmount DESC,
  Bar ASC
;
```

The first sorting criterion causes the query to return the `Bar` or `Bars` that have the biggest `Amount` value. The second one is needed to make sure only one `Bar` is returned if more than one has the same maximum.

The returned rows will not have a guaranteed order. If you need one, use the second query as a derived table and sort the results again as necessary:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
      Foo,
      Bar,
      Amount,
      MaxAmount = MAX(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Bar)
    FROM
      dbo.Table1
    ORDER BY
      MaxAmount DESC,
      Bar ASC
  ) AS s
ORDER BY
  ...
;
```